# Single Sign On using Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, websphere, single-sign-on, ltpa

We are thinking about moving from WebSphere to Tomcat.  In WebSphere, we use [LTPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Lightweight_Third-Party_Authentication) to achieve single sign on between the different applications (running in different physical servers).

What is the best way to get single sign-on between 2 physical machines in Tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat's SSO implementation only provides single sign on between apps on the same (logical) server. However if you want SSO between apps which are located on different servers or even different platforms then Tomcat's SSO option probably won't cut it.

I'd suggest you look at a more robust solution like [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) or [Cloudseal](http://www.cloudseal.com). Cloudseal also has a Tomcat [plugin](http://support.cloudseal.com/customer/portal/articles/352956-first-steps) which may simplify things for you

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat comes with [SSO implementation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Single%20Sign%20On). An other thing you want is [session replication](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/cluster-howto.html#Cluster_Configuration_for_ReplicationTransmitter) between nodes.